# Error on generating self link on pageable resource

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

Make a simple RestController

```
@RestController
public class Controloler
    @Value
    class MyData {
        int value;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/datas", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public PagedResources<Resource<MyData>> getMyData(PagedResourcesAssembler<MyData> assembler,
                                                              @RequestParam(required = false) String param,
                                                              @PageableDefault Pageable pageRequest)
    {
        MyData data = new MyData(1);
        Page<MyData> page = new PageImpl<>(Collections.singletonList(data), pageRequest, 100);
        Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(Controloler.class).getMyData(assembler, param, pageRequest)).withSelfRel();
        return assembler.toResource(page, selfLink);
    }

}
```

When I try to get page `curl "http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12&page=2"` have a problem with self link generation

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "myDataList": [
      {
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12&page=0&size=10"
    },
    "prev": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12&page=1&size=10"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12&page=3&size=10"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12&page=9&size=10"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 10,
    "totalElements": 100,
    "totalPages": 10,
    "number": 2
  }
}
```

In my opinion, self link should be `http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12&page=2&size=10`.

Just now I can solve this problem without using pageable in arguments, just exact params page and size. But, I hope there is some solution with pageable

I've seen that in case of spring-data-rest self have a type of template. But I'd like to get the url I've requested

Answer (score 2):

> In my opinion, self link should be http://localhost:8080/datas?param=12&page=2&size=10.

I agree. In fact, it seems to be a bug. The most recent version of `PagedResourcesAssembler` does it differently:

```
Link selfLink = link.map(it -> it.withSelfRel())//
                .orElseGet(() -> createLink(base, page.getPageable(), Link.REL_SELF));
```

([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/8c5abdb8e6ac12958e1781d5a55008b679690fac/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PagedResourcesAssembler.java#L226))

Buggy versions of that class are doing this:

```
resources.add(createLink(base, null, Link.REL_SELF));
```

The `createLink` method is never passed the needed `Pageable`, but `null` as the second argument.

So, if you can't upgrade to the most recent version you can still work-around it:

```
Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(Controloler.class).getMyData(assembler, param, pageRequest)).withSelfRel();
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(selfLink.expand().getHref());
new HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver().enhance(builder, null, pageRequest);
Link newSelfLink = new Link(builder.build().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Oliver's comment [in an issue opened to address this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1117), the self link should not contain template information, and this is not a bug.