# Missing paging arguments in generated HAL self link

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, hal-json

I am using Spring Boot (2.1.1) to automatically create an HAL REST API of my `JpaRepository` interfaces.

For most cases these interfaces are empty, for example:

```
public interface LevelRepository extends JpaRepository<Level, Long> {}
```

When I open my REST base path, the following link is generated for `levels`:

```
"levels": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/levels{?page,size,sort}",
  "templated": true
}
```

When I follow `http://localhost:8080/admin/levels?size=10` I get the expected page 0 and its 10 elements.
But the given self link is:

```
"self": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/levels{&sort}",
  "templated": true
}
```

I would have expected:

- `http://localhost:8080/admin/levels{?page,size,sort}` or
- `http://localhost:8080/admin/levels?page=0&size=10{&sort}`

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature? Is it possible to get the expected behavior?

I have found the following question on the topic: [Error on generating self link on pageable resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175562/error-on-generating-self-link-on-pageable-resource)
But the given solution does not help, as I am already using a newer version.

**Further informations (Why do I need it?)**

This behavior breaks the flow of following links on the client side.
If the user wants to jump directly to page X or if he wants to change the page size, the original link must be reused.
Not a big workaround, but it is not as nice as templating and following the given self link directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question I found the following [Spring JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1117?jql=text%20~%20%22self%20page%22) describing the same behavior.
According to a comment in the ticket the self link should not be templated.

Although the generated self link is templated, it is probably better to ignore the given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-implement the `self` link by yourself. First of all, I think you use `HATEOAS` library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Let's consider some of your entity - `ExampleEntity`:

```
public class ExampleEntity extends ResourceSupport {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

You extended the `ResourceSupport` class, and it has the `link` property, which we could use using `add` method:

```
ExampleEntity exampleEntity = new ExampleEntity();
Link selfLink = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(YourController.class).slash(id).withSelfRel();
exampleEntity.add(selfLink);
```

So, you can change behaviour of your self link